# Is the company I work for going down?

Tags: contractors

I have been working here for two years and for the past year and a half I've noticed the following:

1. People are leaving pretty much every week
2. There is a recruitment freeze, so when one person leaves they're not replaced.
3. There are a lot of Indian onshore and off shore contracters doing a lot of the work
4. Managers are leaving and not being replaced
5. People are mysteriously disappearing with no word from the business i.e. Fired
6. Instead of employing permenant people the company is taking on contractors
7. Whole teams have left the company

Is this a sign the company is going down? This has been happening for quite some time.

Also, the most senior developer who has been here for 12 years is leaving.

Comment: @Funky In all seriousness I'm not sure the exact question you ask is on-topic here since no one can predict for sure if your company is about to go bankrupt. Perhaps reword it to ask if those are signs of a struggling company (which they are)?

Comment: How can you list all those points and still think things even *might* be okay? If they company is dumb enough to let all this happen without realising this could affect exiting employees morale, then they clearly don't care. Run for it!

Comment: Another alternative than the company going down is the possibility that the management has decided to outsource everything abroad. This short of gentrification happens sometimes when the product is stable and needs no major updates so the engineering team is treated as a cost. In either case you time to disappear will come at some point sooner or later.

Comment: My situation isn't simple I can't just get up and go. My wife is pregnant and I have two kids under 3, so I really want the paternity leave. Also, my sleep situation isn't the best so leaving into a new role would be difficult especially when the new baby comes! :(

Comment: Better to have no paternity leave than no job though.

Comment: True, but they can't just sack me can they? I've been here for over two years. They would surely have to make me redundant.

Comment: Good luck getting pay or paternity pay or a redundancy payment from a company that has ceased to exist...

Comment: Good point...scary stuff, you're right. I don't think the head of the company will lose sleep over not paying people once he's done a runner.

Comment: "they can't just sack me can they?" Hate to break it to you, but uhm ... why not?

Comment: @MaskedMan if the company is in the US and large enough to be covered by FMLA, they can't sack him during paternity leave if he takes it under the provisions of FMLA. They can sack him immediately after he comes back, but not during.

Comment: @alroc It is nowhere mentioned in the question that the company is in the US, and the OP's location is UK, so based on the currently available information that's a pretty big (and irrelevant) if.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it certainly looks like the company is in big trouble, I'd start looking for a new job if I was you.

The company is obviously at the very least slowly restructuring to outsource and not replacing inhouse. So in terms of job security, it appears that you don't have any.

Answer (score 4):

Your company is either failing or has made a decision to outsource the work (or both). There is only one reason you might want to stay: the company needs someone local to coordinate/manage/support the outsource work. If that kind of work interests you, and you can be given that role, things might work out for you.

You need to find out which scenario is happening. Discretely ask somebody in authority at your company (your manager, an executive, owner, etc.).  If they're evasive or offended by your question, then you have an answer on which you can take action. Find a new job and leave. The sooner, the better.

If they give you information, then you have something more to work with and you can make a more informed decision about what's best for your situation.